# How to show properly my data in RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

This is the updated code for my RececlerView to show data in my SQLite Database but still I cant make the data to show in my recycler view but there is no errors in my app.

The applications only show "No API Data" which is from this part of my code.

Toast.makeText(this, "No API Data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

I will show you the codes.

This is a part of my DatabaseHelper the method on Listing the data in myDatabase for RecyclerView.

```
    public boolean checkUser(String email) {

    // array of columns to fetch
    String[] columns = {
            Timerecordshelper.BeneficiaryEntry._ID
    };
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    // selection criteria
    String selection = Timerecordshelper.BeneficiaryEntry.COL_1 + " = ?";

    // selection argument
    String[] selectionArgs = {email};

    // query user table with condition
    /**
     * Here query function is used to fetch records from user table this function works like we use sql query.
     * SQL query equivalent to this query function is
     * SELECT user_id FROM user WHERE user_email = 'test@gmail.com';
     */
    Cursor cursor = db.query(Timerecordshelper.BeneficiaryEntry.TABLE_NAME_IN, //Table to query
            columns,                    //columns to return
            selection,                  //columns for the WHERE clause
            selectionArgs,              //The values for the WHERE clause
            null,                       //group the rows
            null,                      //filter by row groups
            null);                      //The sort order
    int cursorCount = cursor.getCount();
    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    if (cursorCount > 0) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}




public List<TimeinData> getAllTimeinData() {
    // array of columns to fetch
    String[] columns = {
            Timerecordshelper.BeneficiaryEntry.COL_1,
            Timerecordshelper.BeneficiaryEntry.COL_2,
            Timerecordshelper.BeneficiaryEntry.COL_3,
            Timerecordshelper.BeneficiaryEntry.COL_4,
            Timerecordshelper.BeneficiaryEntry.COL_5,

    };
    // sorting orders
    String sortOrder =
            Timerecordshelper.BeneficiaryEntry.COL_1 + " ASC";
    List<TimeinData> TimeList = new ArrayList<TimeinData>();

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();


    Cursor cursor = db.query(Timerecordshelper.BeneficiaryEntry.TABLE_NAME_IN, //Table to query
            columns,    //columns to return
            null,        //columns for the WHERE clause
            null,        //The values for the WHERE clause
            null,       //group the rows
            null,       //filter by row groups
            sortOrder); //The sort order


    // Traversing through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            TimeinData Timerecords = new TimeinData();
            Timerecords.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Timerecordshelper.BeneficiaryEntry.COL_1))));
            Timerecords.setIn(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Timerecordshelper.BeneficiaryEntry.COL_2)));
            Timerecords.setCustomer(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Timerecordshelper.BeneficiaryEntry.COL_3)));
            Timerecords.setBranch(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Timerecordshelper.BeneficiaryEntry.COL_4)));
            Timerecords.setMachine(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Timerecordshelper.BeneficiaryEntry.COL_5)));

            // Adding user record to list

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    // return user list
    return TimeList;
}
```

TimeinRecyclerAdapter.java

```
    package com.example.serviceapplication;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ImageView;

    import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView;
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
    import java.util.ArrayList;


public class TimeinRecyclerAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<TimeinRecyclerAdapter.BeneficiaryViewHolder>  {

private ArrayList<TimeinData> listBeneficiary;
public ImageView overflow;
private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<TimeinData> mFilteredList;


public TimeinRecyclerAdapter(ArrayList<TimeinData> listBeneficiary, Context 
mContext) {
    this.listBeneficiary = listBeneficiary;
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.mFilteredList = listBeneficiary;


}

public class BeneficiaryViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public AppCompatTextView textViewName;
    public AppCompatTextView textViewEmail;
    public AppCompatTextView textViewAddress;
    public AppCompatTextView textViewCountry;


    public BeneficiaryViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        textViewName =  view.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
        textViewEmail = view.findViewById(R.id.textViewEmail);
        textViewAddress = view.findViewById(R.id.textViewAddress);
        textViewCountry = view.findViewById(R.id.textViewCountry);

    }


}




@Override
public BeneficiaryViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int 
viewType) {
    // inflating recycler item view
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.activity_timeinrecycler, parent, false);

    return new BeneficiaryViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final BeneficiaryViewHolder holder, int 
position) {
    holder.textViewName.setText(listBeneficiary.get(position).getId());
    holder.textViewName.setText(listBeneficiary.get(position).getIn());

holder.textViewEmail.setText(listBeneficiary.get(position).getCustomer());

holder.textViewAddress.setText(listBeneficiary.get(position).getBranch());

holder.textViewCountry.setText(listBeneficiary.get(position).getMachine());

}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mFilteredList.size();
}

}
```

Timerecordshelper.java

```
package com.example.serviceapplication;

import android.provider.BaseColumns;

public class Timerecordshelper {



    public static final class BeneficiaryEntry implements BaseColumns {

        public static final String TABLE_NAME_IN = "TABLE_NAME_IN";
        public static final String COL_1 = "Job ID";
        public static final String COL_2 = "Time In";
        public static final String COL_3 = "Customer:";
        public static final String COL_4 = "Branch";
        public static final String COL_5 = "Machine";

    }
}
```

This codes acts as the gettersetter for my Recycleview to get data in SQLite.

TimeinData.java

```
 package com.example.serviceapplication;

 public class TimeinData {

private int id;
private String In;
private String Customer;
private String Branch;
private String Machine;



public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getIn() {
    return In;
}

public void setIn(String In) {
    this.In = In;
}


public String getCustomer() {
    return Customer;
}

public void setCustomer(String Customer) {
    this.Customer = Customer;
}

public String getBranch() {
    return Branch;
}

public void setBranch(String Branch) {
    this.Branch = Branch;
}

public String getMachine() {
    return Machine;
}

public void setMachine(String Machine) {
    this.Machine = Machine;
}
}
```

TimerecordsListActivity.java

```
  package com.example.serviceapplication;




    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Build;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.widget.SearchView;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import android.widget.Toolbar;


    import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
    import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TimerecordsListActivty extends AppCompatActivity {

private AppCompatActivity activity = TimerecordsListActivty.this;
Context context = TimerecordsListActivty.this;
private RecyclerView recyclerViewBeneficiary;
private ArrayList<TimeinData> listBeneficiary;
private TimeinRecyclerAdapter beneficiaryRecyclerAdapter;
private DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
SearchView searchBox;
private ArrayList<TimeinData> filteredList;




@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_timeinrec);
    initViews();
    initObjects();

    Intent intentThatStartedThisActivity = getIntent();
    if (intentThatStartedThisActivity.hasExtra("Job ID")) {

        //get all needed extras intent

        int id = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("ID");
        String in = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Time In");
        String customer = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Customer");
        String branch = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Branch");
        String machine = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Machine");



    }else{

        Toast.makeText(this, "No API Data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

}


/**
 * This method is to initialize views
 */
private void initViews() {
    recyclerViewBeneficiary = (RecyclerView) 
findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewBeneficiary);
}

/**
 * This method is to initialize objects to be used
 */
private void initObjects() {
    listBeneficiary = new ArrayList<>();
    beneficiaryRecyclerAdapter = new TimeinRecyclerAdapter(listBeneficiary, 
 this);

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new 
  LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerViewBeneficiary.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerViewBeneficiary.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerViewBeneficiary.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerViewBeneficiary.setAdapter(beneficiaryRecyclerAdapter);
    databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(activity);

    getDataFromSQLite();

}


/**
 * This method is to fetch all user records from SQLite
 */
private void getDataFromSQLite() {
    // AsyncTask is used that SQLite operation not blocks the UI Thread.
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            listBeneficiary.clear();

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            beneficiaryRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }.execute();
}
}
```

And this is the XML Layouts of my following codes just showing you to understand more about ID i assigned.

Activity_timeinrec.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.example.serviceapplication.TimerecordsListActivty">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>


<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerViewBeneficiary"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="?actionBarSize"/>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

activity_timeinrecycler.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:textColor="#000" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="#000" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:textColor="#000" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewEmail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="#000" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:textColor="#000" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewAddress"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="#000" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:textColor="#000" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewCountry"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="#000" />


    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

I expect that the apps shows all the data in TABLE_NAME_IN, but on the otherhand as I said it only shows the No "API Data".

Comment: Disclaimer:- it's not related to question! you are still using SQLite database! try room database it's easy :)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain exactly how "it is not showing the data properly".

Comment: `problem is the wrong functioning of RecycleView` you have to explain what exactly is wrong. What it does and what you want it to do.

Comment: @MikeM. I already edited my questions pelase take a look thank you.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko I already edited it thank you any comments or help will do.

Comment: ok, you now told us what you want. Now tell us what is the problem. What all this coe does instead?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko I Already change the methods. what do you think the problem is?

Comment: @MikeM.sir anything you notice wrong with this method ? thank you

Comment: looks like `if (intentThatStartedThisActivity.hasExtra("Job ID")) {` is false then. Something wrong with the way you pass the `Job ID` extra

Comment: also `String COL_1 = "Job ID"` if you are using/trying to use this constant as column name - that is a problem. SQLite does not support spaces in column names

Comment: I already found the problem and fixed it but another errors popped out int this line

Comment: Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: Job_ID (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT Job_ID, Time_In, Customer, Branch, Machine FROM Timein ORDER BY Time_In ASC